# How to write variable contents to Console?

Tags: c#

I want to use [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to show the data held in a variable in C#, but I don't know the function to that in C#. If I use `Console.Write()`, I can only do it with a specific variable.

For example I want to vardump everything from data:

```
class Data {
  int total_data = 21,
  int total_page = 1,
  int page = 1,
  int limit = 21
}

var data = new Data();
Console.WriteLine(data.total_data);
```

How can I get something similar to PHP's `var_dump` in C#? I've tried using `Console.WriteLine(data)` but it doesn't work the same way. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library I'm using for this, [ObjectDumper.NET](https://github.com/thomasgalliker/ObjectDumper)
Sample from the README:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var persons = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Name = "John", Age = 20, },
        new Person { Name = "Thomas", Age = 30, },
    };

    var personsDump = ObjectDumper.Dump(persons);

    Console.WriteLine(personsDump);
    Console.ReadLine();


//CONSOLE OUTPUT:
{ObjectDumperSample.Netfx.Person}
  Name: "John"
  Age: 20
{ObjectDumperSample.Netfx.Person}
  Name: "Thomas"
  Age: 30
```

Answer (score 2):

if it is from json to handle or create api,you could try serialize it to JSON string with JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- override the ToString method
- use a record type insted of a class (the complier synthesizes `ToString` for you)
- create a static helper method that takes an object and uses reflection to print values of all properties
- have ToConsole() method on the class
- serialise the object to json and print that